# How can I use DnsQuery to get a SOA record?

Tags: winapi, dns

I am implementing a DNS cache in Windows<sup>†</sup> and I need to know how long to cache negative responses. [RFC 2308](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2308) says to use the TTL of the SOA record I receive, but despite the SOA record being sent to me on the wire (as confirmed by tcpdump), DnsQuery will not expose it to me. For example, running the following C++ code gives me no output:

```
PDNS_RECORDA data = nullptr;
DNS_STATUS rv = dnsQuery("www.google.com", DNS_TYPE_SOA, DNS_QUERY_STANDARD,
                         nullptr, &data, nullptr);
if (data != nullptr) {
    cout << "Yippee" << endl;
}
```

I have tried every value between `0` and `0xFF` as the second argument, but never am I given a SOA record (though several other records come through fine such as A, AAAA, and CNAME). Does anyone know how to get it to behave?

The third parameter accepts various flags. I tried `DNS_QUERY_RETURN_MESSAGE` which looked promising, but seemed to have no visible effect (I am on Windows 7 so it should be supported per [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc982162(v=vs.85).aspx)). I also tried a variety of other flags in desperation. Namely `DNS_QUERY_BYPASS_CACHE`, `DNS_QUERY_RETURN_MESSAGE | DNS_QUERY_BYPASS_CACHE`, `DNS_QUERY_WIRE_ONLY`, and `DNS_QUERY_DONT_RESET_TTL_VALUES`. I have read through the [entire list of query options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc982162(v=vs.85).aspx#DNS_Query_Options) and did not see anything else that looked terribly promising. Note that for each flag, I tried every value between `0` and `0xFF` as the second argument, and looked for anything in the resulting list of type `DNS_TYPE_SOA`.

<sup>†</sup> I know Windows has a perfectly good DNS cache.

Comment: What is the value of `rv` when `data` is null?  Have you tried the `DNS_QUERY_RETURN_MESSAGE` flag in the third parameter?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I have tried `DNS_QUERY_RETURN_MESSAGE` and as far as I can tell it has no effect. The return value for the example above is `DNS_INFO_NO_RECORDS`. tcpdump confirms that a SOA record is received.

Comment: Have you tried any other flags? `DNS_QUERY_ACCEPT_TRUNCATED_RESPONSE`, `DNS_QUERY_BYPASS_CACHE`, `DNS_QUERY_WIRE_ONLY`, etc?  If you don't provide what diagnostic steps you have tried so far, this is likely to get closed as "off topic".

Comment: in [this question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/62be5a70-b101-4a61-83ee-562841f1ef9b/dnsquery-dnstypeaxfr-returns-only-soa-record), the poster complains about `DnsQuery()` returning SOA records for AXFR requests. Do you still have your problem if you provide an [`IP4_ARRAY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682139.aspx) in the `pExtra` parameter of `DnsQuery()` to specify a particular DNS server IP to query? That option is not mentioned in the `DnsQuery()` documentation, but it is demonstrated in various MSDN examples.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Hmm, that looked promising. I wasn't able to change anything by providing a `pExtra` though. [This is the code](https://gist.github.com/brownhead/6320f169370f985256b8) I used to test this.

Comment: @brownhead remove the "www." before the hostname and it'll return the SOA record.